# Why my iOS Distribution signing identity is revoked?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

[image]

I can`t find valid signing identity in target settings. After i requested signing identity from XCode->Preferences->Accounts menu (see picture), my identity is revoked always. And after i relaunch xcode, i've not any signing identity for my distribution provision profile. I tried to remove ALL stuff from keychain, re-create distribution certificate and provision profiles, but anythings doesnt work. Previously i successful saw iOS Distribution identity with status Valid on my another mac, but i can't upload binary from it. Maybe i should delete something from Mac, where identity is valid?

Comment: How to fix this, suddenly my Xcode also showing all my signing identities as revoked

Comment: I'm developing an app for a non-profit that only has first gen iPads available which support 5.1. So I'm on XCode 6 and hitting this exact issue. Has anyone figured out what the deal is?

Answer (score 1):

Click + button to create new iOS Distribution. And if you provide whats the result, would be perfect.

if xcode didnt correct or create new one. Do it on member center developer.apple.com. Then you should be able to see it.

Comment: You found answer of this question same issue is with me